# issue with getting the value from array of int's after passing a function pointer to the array

Tags: c

I am trying to get value from array of type `int` and i cant figure out what i am doing wrong.
the function gets two pointers, one to the array and one the another int variable, and i want the function to change this other var ("balance" is the name of the var) with a value from the array. the function looks like this:

```
int Buy(int *balance, int *prices){
    int item=0;
    printf("\nPlease enter product number to commit purchase: ");
    scanf("%d", &item);
    *balance -= *(prices+item);
    return 1;
}
```

and the main function looking something like this:

```
void main( int argc, char *argv[]){

    int *ptr_to_prices, *ptr_to_balance;
    int balance = atoi(argv[2]);
    ptr_to_balance = &balance;

    Init(argv[1], balance);
    ptr_to_prices = displayProducts(atoi(argv[2]));
    Buy(ptr_to_balance, ptr_to_prices);
}
```

bottom line, i need the `Buy` function to get the value of balance which i initialized the program with and subtract from it the value of `prices[item]`.

thanks

UPDATE:
here is displayProducts():

```
int *displayProducts(int balance){

    printf("-----------Available Products-----------\n");
    putchar('\n');

    int row=0;
    const char *products[8];
    int prices[8];
    char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE + 1]; // ptr to the current input line
    FILE *fp;

    fp = fopen("machinedata.txt", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error while opening the file.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(line, MAX_LINE_SIZE, fp)) {

        char *next_ptr = NULL;
        char *next_item = strtok_s(line, ",;", &next_ptr);

        while (next_item != NULL){
            char *item_ptr = NULL;
            char *name = strtok_s(next_item, "-", &item_ptr);
            if (name == NULL)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to scan name out of [%s]\n", next_item);
                break;
            }
            int price;
            next_item = strtok_s(NULL, " ,", &item_ptr);
            //assert(next_item != NULL);
            if (strcmp(name," ")){
                if (sscanf(next_item, "%d", &price) != 1)
                    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to convert [%s] to integer\n", next_item);
                else if (balance > price){

                    products[row] = name;
                    prices[row] = price;
                    printf("%d) %s:%d\n", row+1, products[row], prices[row]);
                    row++;
                }

                next_item = strtok_s(NULL, ",;", &next_ptr);
            }
        }
    }
    return prices;
}
```

Comment: Post `displayProducts()`.  Suspect memory allocation issue there.

Comment: Also, it'd be helpful if you could describe what problem you're seeing.

Answer (score 3):

I think, you need to change

```
printf("%d\n", prices+item);
```

to

```
printf("%d\n", *(prices+item) );
```

as `%d` expects an `int` argument. To print a pointer you need to use `%p`.

That said, using the `argv[n]` directly without checking for `argc` can lead to erratic behavior causing segmentation fault, if command line args are not supplied properly.

---

**EDIT:**

The problem here is, you're returning the address of a automatic local variable (array) `prices` from `displayProducts()`. Using the return value will result in [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Also, `prices[item]` might be more intuitive.

Comment: the `printf("%d\n", prices+item);` was for debugging purpose. as you can see one line down i used it as you suggest

Comment: so what i dont understand is why when i add this line to the end of main; `printf("%d", *(ptr_to_prices+1));` i get the correct value from the array..?